# Preventing text between figures

Tags: floats

I have 6 figures I want to include in a paper one after the other. When placing the figures only 2 fit on a page and the space at the bottom of the page is being filled by a few lines of text from the next section. Is there any way to prevent this and just have all 6 of the figures before the text begins. I have tried using `\newpage`and that doesn't work. I would prefer not to resize my figures to solve the problem also.

Comment: You could remove the `figure` enviromnment for the six figures. If you need captions for the figures, use the `captionof` command from the `capt-of` package. `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package might also be an option if you want to stick to the `figure` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to use the `[p]` placement directive for each `figure` environment. I suggest you use three separate `figure` environments, each containing two graphs and two associated `\caption` directives.

Here's an MWE that illustrates the recommended setup. Running text is on page 1; pages 2, 3, and 4 contain the six graphs, and running text continues on page 5.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % filler text

\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1}
\caption{First figure}
\vspace{1in} % or whatever spacing is appropriate
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2}
\caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig3}
\caption{Third figure}
\vspace{1in}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig4}
\caption{Fourth figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig5}
\caption{Fifth figure}
\vspace{1in}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig6}
\caption{Sixth figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-10] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

If the six graphs have to be placed at the very beginning of the document, use the same setup as above but insert `\clearpage` after the third `\end{figure}` statement.

Comment: For clarity this problem is occurring in the middle of a large paper. I tried using [p] as you suggest but it places the figures at the end of the document rather than in the middle. EDIT: I have solved the problem using multiple vspace commands to manually space it. Not the prettiest solution but it did the job

Comment: @JamesHunt - If using `[p]` forces the floats to show up at the very end of the document, the root cause is almost certainly that the heights of the floats exceed the value of `\textheight`. (Aside: Have you tried reducing the argument of `\vspace` to something less than `1in`?) Anyway, changing the placement directives from `[p]` to `[p!]` and inserting `\clearpage` immediately after the third `figure` envirionment should fix the issue.